# Analysis question about finding the limit.

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the sequence $(c_n)_n$ defined recursively by $c_1=1/2$ and then $c_{n+1} = \frac{3+c_n}{4}$. Show that this sequence increases to a finite limit $L$ and find $L$.

I just need perhaps one or two Theorems/definitions to help me solve this. 
I already know the limit definition for the basics of sequences...

Comment: If you have a sequence recursively defined by $x_{n+1} = f(x_n)$ with a continuous $f$, the limit, if it exists, must satisfy $\lambda = f(\lambda)$.

Comment: Try to prove that it is increasing and bounded above. This will show that it converges. To find the limit, what can you say about the limits of the sequences $\{c_n\}_{n=1}^\infty $ and $\{c_{n+1}\}_{n=1}^\infty$?

Answer (score 1):

If there is a limit, it satisfies $x = (3+x)/4,$ so the only solution is $x=1.$ As to whether the limit exists, let $c_n = 1+ \epsilon_n.$ Then

$$1+\epsilon_{n+1} = (4+\epsilon_n)/4 = 1 + \epsilon_n/4,$$ so $\epsilon_n$ is going to $0$ exponentially fast.